# Can input to 3D convolution be a list of 4D arrays, where rows of list are samples?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have 3d models obtained from .mat file of dimensions 182 x 199x3 and 22 frames. I have a total sample of 100 such data. 
After loading to the python I obtained a list of 100 arrays [Numpy array, numpy array...] whcih i converted to arrays and dimesions are [100,22,182,199,3]. Technically this looks like 5D input which conv3d requires but, i was wondering cant i feed list of arrays to input keeping the bachsize whatever I wish like 20/32 or anything.

Answer (score 0):

As per your specification of the data.

```
==>> Basic size of the data is 182 X 199 X 3
==>> 22 is the total frames
==>> so one batch of the data is [22(n_channel)X 182 X 199 X 3]
==>> if you want to know the total shape of the data it would be 100 X 22 X 182 X 199 X 3
==>> and if you wish for a batch_size of say 30 the shape would be [30 X 22 X 182 X 199 X 3]
```

So yes you can feed the data as per your requirement of batch_size

Answer (score 0):

You can input any 5D array.

You cannot input "lists" of arrays, but "an" array with the required batch size:

```
batch = full_array[:batch_size]   
batch2 = full_array[batch_size : 2* batch_size]
```

But Keras automatically iterates the batches from a single array in:

```
model.fit(full_inputs_array, full_outputs_array, batch_size=32, ...)
```